# How to snap my player to the ground with a Raycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have weird movement when I reach the top of stairs or when I walk down stairs including skipping down them so what I have done is based on other threads I've seen is have two bools to check if the is player grounded using the last frame and current frame, then I use that value in a Raycast where I check for the hit distance and then use that distance value to snap my player down. From what I've debugged, when the player "skips" down stairs and isGrounded turns false, the hit.distance is never more than 1.6f so I'm trying to snap my player vertically by that amount.

I just don't know what line of code actually pushes/snaps the player down vertically.

```
bool isGrounded;
bool wasPreviouslyGrounded = true;

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 3f))
{
    var checkGrounded = wasPreviouslyGrounded && !controller.isGrounded;

    if (checkGrounded && velocity.y < 0) // Velocity will be < 0 only if player is grounded
    {
        if (hit.distance < 1.6f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y + controller.height / 2, hit.point.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you use the gravity to let the player fall naturally and stop when he reached the floor ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem comes from the fact that your raycast collide with every layer so if probably collide first with the player collider (that's why if never more than 1.6, the usual height of players in Unity). I think you should add a layer mask and put inside it all the layer on which player can be and exclude other. Your player gameobject (or at least the one containing the CharacterController) should be on a specific layer named like 'Player'.

Here is how I would do it :

In parameters

```
[Tooltip("The floor LayerMask")]
[SerializeField] LayerMask FloorMask;
```

In your method

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 3f, FloorMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
{
   //Your function
}
```

My answer only concerns the raycast, I have no opinion on your "two bools check"